# Perfect Circle internal content height unknown

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm having issues figuring out how to make a perfect circle without knowing the exact height of the content (image) inside the circle.

I have multiple images (jumbo titles) with circles around them but the image inside is of different height. How would I have it so it appears as a perfect circle? for each one.

css below

```
  .jumbo-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HA3bQ/49/

Comment: Calculate the height of the image with javascript and then update the css perhaps?

Comment: do the images all have the same width?

Comment: can you change the html a little bit?

Comment: possibly, depends how much :D

Comment: I was thinking you could use something like this https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php to keep the height and the width exactly the same

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what there doing there.

Comment: @Phreak did you even have a look at the solution I gave you?

Comment: Yes my apologize both answers helped you explained it throughly so I gave Ya the correct answer :))

Comment: @Phreak Thanks. Was just wondering if you looked at it because you didn't comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT2: Updated.
EDIT: FORGOT THE width! Hold up!

If you are open to JavaScript solution (no jQuery) with a CSS trick to center it:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbo-title">
    <div class="living-icon"></div>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Relaxed Living">
</div>
```

JS:

```
    function init() {
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].parentElement.style.height = Math.max(images[i].width, images[i].height) + "px";
            images[i].parentElement.style.width = Math.max(images[i].width, images[i].height) + "px";
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

CSS:

```
.jumbo-title {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     margin-right: -50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     background-color: red;
     padding: 50px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
     -ms-border-radius: 50%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-align: center;
  }
 .jumbo-title img {
      vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .middle {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HA3bQ/54/

Answer (score 1):

you could use this simple jquery:

```
var cw = $('.jumbo-title').width();
$('.jumbo-title').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

Basically jquery will check your element width and will add the same number (px) to  height

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/HA3bQ/51/)**

In the fiddle it may look bad because of the padding you have used. then you may need just to center the image inside the container

Comment: what if i have multiple jumbo titles

Comment: Well... You could use a class for each, coudn't you? (an old fiddle of mine: http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/y5x01vfg/)